# determinate the boundary of $D$ , over $f(x,y,z)= e^x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Considering the set :

$D = \{ (x,y,z)\in R^3 : x^2+(y+2)^2+z^2=4, y+2\ge \sqrt{x^2+z^2}  \}$

(knowing that $f: D\to R$) with $f(x,y,z)=e^x$

How can I calculate the boundary of $D$ ($\partial D$), in order to find out the extrema of $f$ bounded on $\partial D$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sphere of radius $2$ centered at $(0,-2,0)$, and the inside of a cone of axis $y$ shifted $2$ units on the $y$ axis, in other words a cone whose "peak" is exactly at the center of the sphere.

The cone and the sphere intersect at $y=\sqrt{2}-2$, forming the circle 
$
x^2+z^2 = 2
,$ which is the boundary of $D$.